MudText - on ENTER key, determine contents of selected line then act accordingly
I'm trying to develop a custom notepad editor. Currently I'm using the MudText component of MudBlazor for this.
The behaviour I'm seeking is that when a user hits ENTER on their keyboard, I want to check the contents of the selected line and run some custom logic in the KeyPress event.

If current line contains text then create new line/paragraph as normal.
If current line contains no text then prevent text from being added to the editor and popup a menu at that location instead. Here is some code I was playing with. But could not work it out after that. Any help appreciated.

@code
{
    string sampleText = "wwswswLorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua.";
}

<MudTextField T="string" Label="Multiline" KeyDownPreventDefault="_preventDefault" Variant="Variant.Text" Text="@sampleText" Lines="50" AutoGrow="true" Immediate="true" OnKeyDown="@HandleKeyDown" />


@code {
    bool _preventDefault;
    protected void HandleKeyDown(KeyboardEventArgs e)
    {
        _preventDefault = e.Key == "Enter" && ...?
    }
}


Listen to keydown event and validate enter or other buttons. Then check the cursor position and get the line text, then open a menu or switch the line. May I know is it correct?

I found an issue, when we have KeyDownPreventDefault="_preventDefault" in MudTextField and click enter when the page is just init rendered, it will still switch the line. But the next time I click enter, it will be prevented to switch the line. Maybe a bug.

I write a sample to test in my side, the validation method for "where is the cursor" and "switch to the next line" are all written in js. We are now trying to write blazor app. I think we'd better to reduce using js. But MudBlazor doesn't have builtin feature for your requiremtn..

@Yogi - if user pastes then nothing. rule is you cannot enter text on a new line until you've hit enter and selected from a list a value. Think screenplay editor where you select whether its a dialogue or action etc. which then affects the formatting of that line.

@TinyWang, I am very new to Blazor. I am testing it out to see how easy it is to code when you're a C# guy and nor proficient with javascript. These things are all fairly easy to achieve in WinForms. Im trying to gauge if I'm going to get bogged down with Blazor or not. I appreciate the work that has gone into this MudBlazor suite it's really amazing.

@Yogi - I will try to re-explain later today and thankyou very much for your and Tiny Wang's time so far with this.

Thank you for your response, and pls update your question if you have other concerns.
